# Adding polylines in asynctask android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

i'm having performance issues adding polylines and thought that maybe it'll be possible to add them in a separate class extending AsyncTask. However as i learned that UI elements can't be added in such way (and polylines are UI elements).

Why i'm having performance issues while drawing polylines? Well, my polylines are drawn not from pos A to pos B but from my current location to destination (which is hardcoded for the sake of application atm). So the polylines are drawn when onLocationChange listener is executed and thus my application requires lots of proccessing power.

Any ideas how to use AsyncTask on this occasion?

This is the main class:

```
 mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
                    // Get positions!
                    currentPOS = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude());
                    LatLng dst = new LatLng(58.378249, 26.714673);
                    CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPOS, 13);
                    mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dst).title("SCHOOL!"));
                    /*
                        // Remove comments to add marker to Liivi 2!
                        mMap.addMaker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPOS).title("My POS"));
                     */
                    if (currentPOS != null) {
                        //This is supposed to show directions
                        DirectionAPI directionAPI = new DirectionAPI(currentPOS, dst);
                        GoogleResponse googleResponse = null;
                        try {
                            googleResponse = (GoogleResponse) directionAPI.execute().get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Log.e("CATCH","INTERRUPDED");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            Log.e("CATCH","EXECUTIONEXCEPTION");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (googleResponse.isOk()){
                            DrivingDirection drivingDirection =  new DrivingDirection(googleResponse.getJsonObject());
                            polyline = drivingDirection.getTotalPolyline();
                            new drawPath(mMap,polyline).execute();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is the Async for path drawing (which will result in an error due to UI conflict):

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Kevin on 7.10.2015.
 */
public class drawPath extends AsyncTask{

    private static ArrayList<LatLng> polyline;
    private static GoogleMap mMap;

    public drawPath(GoogleMap map, ArrayList<LatLng> polyline){
        this.mMap = map;
        this.polyline = polyline;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < polyline.size() - 1; i++) {
            LatLng src = polyline.get(i);
            LatLng dest = polyline.get(i + 1);

            // mMap is the Map Object
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(
                    new PolylineOptions().add(
                            new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                            new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude)
                    ).width(2).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true)
            );
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `onMyLocationChange` firing too frequently?  If that's the issue you can check to see if the location has changed by a certain threshold, maybe 10 meters.  Ignore it if it's below that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in a way that i did not add every polyline map separately but whole polyline. For example, before i had my location about 4km away from destination and it had 280 polylines between. On every onLocationChange these polylines were drawn one-by-one to map. Now they're all added at once - AsyncTask will create polylines in the background and in the post-execute they will be added.

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    for (int z = 0; z < polyline.size(); z++) {
        LatLng point = polyline.get(z);
        options.add(point);
    }
    return options;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline((PolylineOptions) result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
ublic class DrawrootTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private Context context;
public static boolean flagCompleted = false;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private double source_lat = 0.0;
private double source_long = 0.0;
private double dest_lat = 0.0;
private double dest_long = 0.0;
Userdata userdata;
String tag = "DrawRootTask";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static double dist, time;
private Polyline line;
String distanceText = "";
String durationText = "";

public DrawrootTask(Context context, LatLng source, LatLng destination,
        GoogleMap googleMap) {
    source_lat = source.latitude;
    source_long = source.longitude;
    dest_lat = destination.latitude;
    dest_long = destination.longitude;

    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    this.context = context;
    userdata = Userdata.getinstance(context);

}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(
            R.string.please_wait));
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String json = "";

    // constructor
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    HashMap<String, String> keyValue = new HashMap<String, String>();
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(source_lat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(source_long));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString.append(Double.toString(dest_lat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(dest_long));
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");

    // defaultHttpClient
    String url = urlString.toString();
    FetchUrl fetchurl = new FetchUrl();
    json = fetchurl.fetchUrl(url, keyValue);

    Log.e("Buffer Error", json);
    return json;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

        for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
            LatLng src = list.get(z);
            LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
            line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                            new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                    // .width(8).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
                    .width(8)
                    .color(context.getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.actionbar_color)).geodesic(true));
            Log.i("draw root", "" + "" + line.toString());
        }
        JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
        JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject duration = steps.getJSONObject("duration");
        JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
        distanceText = distance.getString("text");
        durationText = duration.getString("text");
        Log.i("draw root", "" + distance.toString());
        dist = Double.parseDouble(distance.getString("text").replaceAll(
                "[^\\.0123456789]", ""));
        time = Double.parseDouble(duration.getString("text").replaceAll(
                "[^\\.0123456789]", ""));
        userdata.setDistance(distanceText);
        userdata.setTime(durationText);
        Log.d(tag, "distace is " + dist + " time is " + time);
        flagCompleted = true;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("draw root", "" + e);

    }
}

private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

}