# How to draw path between multiple markers in android

Tags: android, dictionary, marker

Hello I am working with android .I had created an app to locate users location with an interval.I can plot markers with corresponding values of latitude and longitude arraylist. Now I want to draw path between these markers.I used the below code to plot two markers. So how can I connect all my markers in the order of my arraylist .Please help me .Thanks in advance.

```
private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                PathJsonParser parser = new PathJsonParser();
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

            try {

                // traversing through routes
                for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

                    for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                        points.add(position);
                    }

                    polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                    polyLineOptions.width(2);
                    polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
                }

                googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
            }catch(NullPointerException e) {

                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "Please check your internet connection !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //If data == null it will pass here
            }

        }
    }


    private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {
        String waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|"
                + start.latitude + "," + start.latitude;

        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String params = waypoints + "&" + sensor;
        String output = "json";
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + params;
        return url;
    }
```

Comment: Please check this answer, Hope this would help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33094777/5093415

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED));
line.setPoints(points);
```

where points is list of LatLng

Comment: note that: using polyline draws a line between markers ignoring the roads (off-road), so the line could be crossing buildings for example, thats why its better to get a list of adjacent LatLong from google Directions api, whichs gives accurate list of points which are actually on road, then use polyline.
refer to this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094240/how-to-get-driving-distance-between-two-locations/33094777#33094777

Comment: @NouranS.Ahmad The given link is not showing how to draw path between multiple markers. Is there any valid link for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

lineOptions.setPoints(points);
polyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        polyline.setWidth(5);
        polyline.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Where `points` is an ArrayList of type `Latlng`