# How to get total travel time between two location in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I implement to get distance between two location in google map in android but i have not idea how to get travel time for this two location ? I refer many example but i can not understand. Give me example

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094240/how-to-get-driving-distance-between-two-locations

Comment: plz check http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/  and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start?c and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094240/how-to-get-driving-distance-between-two-locationssw=1

Answer (score 0):

You can get travel time from [Google Direction API] -

Link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start#sample-request

Provide your origin & destination in the URL and you'll get a JSON Response.

You can then find travel time in the response as:

routes(JSONArray) -> legs(JSONArray) -> duration(JSONObject)

Reference Link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests